# Not in scope: data constructor `Song' - Haskell

Tags: database, haskell, types, constructor, scope

```
type Song = (String, String, Int) --(title, artist, sales)

database :: [Song]
database = [("Amon Amarth","Ravens flight", 1), 
  ("Amon Amarth","Shield wall", 11),
  ("Amon Amarth","The way of vikings", 105),
  ("Elijah Nang","Journey to the west", 1000),
  ("Elijah Nang","Tea house", 7),
  ("Pink Floyd","Wish you were here", 123),
  ("Amon Amarth","Raise your horns", 9001),
  ("NLE Choppa","Walk 'em down'", 69420),
  ("Elijah Nang","Kumite", 1337),
  ("NLE Choppa","Shotta flow 6", 511),
  ("Pink Floyd","Comfortably numb", 9),
  ("Pink Floyd","Shotta flow 6", 711), -- changed to match the name of an nle choppa song as requested
  ("Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart","Requiem", 10203948),
  ("Elijah Nang","Kenjutsu water style", 1),
  ("NLE Choppa","Shotta flow 5", 1),
  ("Pink Floyd","High hopes", 1),
  ("Amon Amarth","Deceiver of the gods", 1),
  ("Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart","Turkish march", 1),
  ("Chance The Rapper","Cocoa butter kisses", 1),
  ("Chance The Rapper","Favourite song", 1),
  ("Chance The Rapper","Hot shower", 1),
  ("Chance The Rapper","High hopes", 1)] 


getTrackSale :: Int -> String -> String -> String --(index, artist, track, sales)
getTrackSale index artist track
  | ((getArtist(database!!index) == artist) && (getTrack(database!!index) == track)) = getTrackSale(database!!index)
  | otherwise = getTrackSale(index + 1 artist track)


task2 = getTrackSale(0 "Chance The Rapper" "Hot Shower")

getArtist :: Song -> String
getArtist (Song y _ _) = y

getTrack :: Song -> String
getTrack (Song _ z _) = z

getSale :: Song -> Int
getSale (Song _ _ x) = x
```

I cannot figure out what this means or how to solve it, I've written identical functions to the three "get" functions before and they had no trouble, but i did use the "type" declaration before, so i imagine It's that. i have sample code using a identical type declaration in that works fine so im just a little lost here.

Comment: Next time, please include the full text of the type error you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write

```
type Song = (String, String, Int)
```

which means that `Song` is a *type synonym* for `(String, String, Int)`. That is, a `Song` is actually just an ordered triple, constructed using the ordered-triple constructor `(,,)`. But later you write

```hs
getArtist :: Song -> String
getArtist (Song y _ _) = y

getTrack :: Song -> String
getTrack (Song _ z _) = z

getSale :: Song -> Int
getSale (Song _ _ x) = x
```

pattern matching on a (nonexistent) `Song` data constructor.

You can stick with the type synonym by writing

```
getArtist :: Song -> String
getArtist (y, _, _) = y
```

and so on. Or you can make `Song` its own datatype:

```
data Song = Song
  { getArtist :: String
  , getTrack :: String
  , getSale :: Int }
```

in which case you'll have to modify your `database` definition to use the `Song` constructor. Using a custom datatype declaration is more idiomatic and more self-documenting, and it makes Haskell's type system do more of the work of helping you find mistakes in your code. As a general rule, I recommend that Haskell beginners avoid type synonyms altogether, and that more experienced Haskell programmers use them only very rarely in certain special circumstances. In particular, type synonyms are very useful in combination with the `TypeFamilies` extension, and somewhat useful in combination with the `ConstraintKinds` and `RankNTypes` extensions, but otherwise tend to be more confusing than helpful, in my experience.

Comment: thank you for your response, i have used custom datatypes before but was unsure then if it was the right choice so tried the type synonym thing hoping it would open some more doors for me, converting abck has solved at least half of my functions errors lol.

Comment: @KaneAustin, when writing in Haskell, there's no reason to fear custom types. It's not at all unusual for me to write a custom type just because I think it will be useful for a single helper function. Types are cheap!